# x-httpd-php5s <-- s! on Bluehost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, handler

I'm trying to replicate a web-site on a test-server. However, on the test-server, `.php` files don't get interpreted. I found that the cause is a `.htaccess` file in the document root. Its contents:

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    /web/$1
```

How do I configure Apache2/PHP5 to support the handler `application/x-httpd-php5s`? Is there any software-package which makes this handler available?

*Update:* It may be a handler specific to Bluehost.com. Am currently investigating this...

*Update 2:* To avoid having to change the `.htaccess` file, which would introduce inconsistencies, I added a handler "application/x-httpd-php5s" to Apache:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php
Action application/x-httpd-php5s /cgi-bin/php5
```

However, that handler will not behave as on the production server, where it causes the PHP interpreter to use a `php.ini` in the document root and use it for all subdirectories. A somewhat ugly workaround is, for example, to symlink that `php.ini` to the global `php.ini` on the test-server.

Comment: If you're unwilling ot modify a bugged .htaccess file, are you going to be **more** willing to edit  your friggin apache server files?  I don't think so, ergo you're acting pretty trollish.

Comment: Deleted my answer, I mistook `application/x-httpd-php5s` for `application/x-httpd-php5-source` \*facepalm\*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have been using Bluehost for a long time.
What you are talking about is only the php.ini file that gets loaded.

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php

Loads a single php.ini file for all sites hosted on there server. That php.ini file is usually found in the public_html folder.

If you change it to;

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php

Then the server will look for php.ini in the same folder as your .htaccess file.

The "s" at the after the 5 means single.

Answer (score 2):

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s is the **source** handler.

All you have to do is change it to   `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php`

Comment: I don't want to modify the web-site's code. And, also, I assume that your proposed change breaks functionality. There is a "php.ini" in the document root, and - if I understand it correctly - the "x-httpd-php5s" causes that file to be interpreted as PHP configuration for all the ".php" files in sub-directories.

Comment: In what way is the ".htaccess" file bugged? Before modifying anything, I want to replicate the original environment as closely as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have since convinced my client to move away from Bluehost, for performance reasons. So it's a non-issue for us now. However, from what I've seen, I am pretty certain that `x-httpd-php5s` this is a Bluehost specific handler.

Comment: Which hosting solution did you move the client to?